# Respecting Scala License when distributing binary jar

Tags: scala, jar, software-distribution

Most libraries contain a `LICENSE` text file somewhere in their jar or at least a license URL in their Manifest. This is not the case for the scala library jar.

How do I properly respect the [Scala License](http://www.scala-lang.org/license.html) when distributing an application which includes the binary `scala-library-2.11.7.jar` (no source code)? Do I manually bundle a LICENSE file or just include a link somewhere in my README?